# Slurm: Rename a particular line in a folder

Tags: unix, slurm, hpc

I'm attempting to use a for loop to repeatedly change a file's line. It's my code.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Example SLURM Batch Script for Running Multiple Tasks

# SLURM Configuration
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --time=30-00:00:00
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=1gb
#SBATCH --partition=example_partition

# Define the number of tasks in the array
#SBATCH --array=1-2

# Print out some information about the environment
echo "Hostname: $(hostname)"
echo "Starting at: $(date)"
echo "Running on hosts: $SLURM_NODELIST"
echo "Running on $SLURM_NNODES nodes."
echo "Running on $SLURM_NPROCS processors."
echo "Current working directory: $(pwd)"

# Export environment variable
export MY_VARIABLE=1234

# Loop through tasks
for ((i=1; i<=$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_COUNT; i++)); do
    # Format the index with leading zeros (e.g., 001, 002, ..., 030)
    index=$(printf "%04d" $i)

    # Modify parameters for each task
    sed -i "s/input_file = .*/input_file = task$index.in/" task_config.ini

done

echo "Program completed with exit code $? at: $(date)"
```

Still, no changes are being made to the parameters. I want to use Slurm, but I can't use'sed'. Exists a slurm function that is compatible?

It was my idea to use the cluster and repeatedly change the lines. What'm I not getting? Is there a Slurm method for carrying this out?

Comment: what is the content of `task_config.ini`? If you got multiple lines the first run of the loop will replace all of these with `input_file = task$index.in`, right?  I guess you want to have a separate `task_config_001.ini` file for each of the tasks?

Comment: It's just a file with text. Yes, that's right. 
I do not want a separate file for each task. It should be inputfile = task001.in replace in task_config.ini and then it runs an executable using task_config.ini --- I forgot to add the srun to the code excerpt.
In the next iteration,  inputfile = task002.in should replace task001.in in task_config.ini and then run the executable again.

Comment: In that case you just keep the `task_config.ini` intact and create separate files out of it.

Comment: I guess I am getting what you want to do. Updated my answer with links to SLURM job arrays tutorials.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What does master_input.ini does?

Comment: re `master_input.ini`: I intended it to be some template from which one create `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` specific inputs. But in the links/scripts included in the edited answer there are simpler ways to achieve this, I think. Thank you for an interesting question. I was able to upgrade my ideas about SLURM job arrays :)

Comment: Am afraid it doesn't work on my end... "sed -i "s/input_file = .*/input_file = task$index.in/" task_config.ini" This in ubuntu works, but in slurm doesn't. I don't seem to understand the reason to it..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256823/discussion-between-darked89-and-rkerr).

Answer (score 1):

This is just the `sed` part:

```
task_num = $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_COUNT
for ((i=1; i<=$task_num; i++)); 
    do echo $i; 
    index=$(printf "%04d" $i); 
    echo $index;  
    sed  "s//input_file = .*/input_file = task$index.ini/g" master_input.ini > task$index.ini; 

done
```

I guess this is still not a proper way to have working inputs for an array job, but at least it should solve the `sed` issue.

**edit**

There are few ways to use `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` to to provide the program with distinct input/parameters.

1. [U. Calgary](https://rcs.ucalgary.ca/How_to_use_array_jobs_in_SLURM)
2. [U. of Florida](https://help.rc.ufl.edu/doc/SLURM_Job_Arrays)

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH --job-name=mega_array   # Job name
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL         # Mail events (NONE, BEGIN, END, FAIL, ALL)
#SBATCH --mail-user=gatorlink@ufl.edu # Where to send mail  
#SBATCH --nodes=1                   # Use one node
#SBATCH --ntasks=1                  # Run a single task
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=1gb           # Memory per processor
#SBATCH --time=00:10:00             # Time limit hrs:min:sec
#SBATCH --output=array_%A-%a.out    # Standard output and error log
#SBATCH --array=1-5                 # Array range
# This is an example script that combines array tasks with
# bash loops to process many short runs. Array jobs are convenient
# for running lots of tasks, but if each task is short, they
# quickly become inefficient, taking more time to schedule than
# they spend doing any work and bogging down the scheduler for
# all users. 
pwd; hostname; date

#Set the number of runs that each SLURM task should do
PER_TASK=1000

# Calculate the starting and ending values for this task based
# on the SLURM task and the number of runs per task.
START_NUM=$(( ($SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID - 1) * $PER_TASK + 1 ))
END_NUM=$(( $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID * $PER_TASK ))

# Print the task and run range
echo This is task $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID, which will do runs $START_NUM to $END_NUM

# Run the loop of runs for this task.
for (( run=$START_NUM; run<=END_NUM; run++ )); do
  echo This is SLURM task $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID, run number $run
  #Do your stuff here
done

date
```

3. [Ronin blog](https://blog.ronin.cloud/slurm-job-arrays/)

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=myarrayjob
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --array=1-10

# Specify the path to the config file
config=/path/to/config.txt

# Extract the sample name for the current $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID
sample=$(awk -v ArrayTaskID=$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID '$1==ArrayTaskID {print $2}' $config)

# Extract the sex for the current $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID
sex=$(awk -v ArrayTaskID=$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID '$1==ArrayTaskID {print $3}' $config)

# Print to a file a message that includes the current $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID, the same name, and the sex of the sample
echo "This is array task ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}, the sample name is ${sample} and the sex is ${sex}." >> output.txt
```